# How Much Did Game of Thrones Cost to Produce, in Total?

Tags: game-of-thrones, production

*Game of Thrones* has been a massively popular, highly polished production for nearly a decade. Now that the entire show is done (and presumably all production has been definitively billed), I'm curious about the total cost of its production. A teaser trailer for the behind-the-scenes documentary airing next week suggested that, at least in the final seasons, each episode cost as much as a major feature film to produce. I'm primarily wondering how much economic activity the show itself generated.

I am specifically interested in the costs related to *making* the show, once actual production of show-specific elements began (so, I'm willing to ignore things like the cost of licensing the franchise from GRRM, and am not interested in costs associated with things like manufacturing merchandise or producing spin-off video games).

But any costs like staffing, travel, permitting, advertising for the show itself, or things like that are what I'm looking for. I'm open to any estimates available, as long as they are clear about what types of costs they are considering or leaving out.

#### What was the total cost of producing the *GoT* television series?

Comment: Advertising isn't usually in *production* budget, but costs a lot. If such additional costs were included, it could raise the total cost to, perhaps, even one billion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Approximate $560 Million

HBO doesn't confirm budget figures but we can estimate, according to this [source](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/04/12/how-much-it-costs-to-produce-an-episode-of-game-of-thrones.html):

> The show’s CGI dragons and epic battle scenes don’t come cheap. Season eight will be the most expensive one yet, with episodes estimated to cost a whopping $15 million each.
>
> The show’s previous two seasons have been pricey as well: Starting with season six, a single “Game of Thrones” episode cost around $10 million to produce, according to an exclusive feature in the April 2016 print edition of Entertainment Weekly. That marks a budget increase of around $4 million per episode, up from the approximate $6 million earlier episodes cost.

So with a little math:

Season 1 to season 5, $6 million per episode (50 episodes) = **$300 million**.
Season 6 and Season 7, $10 million per episode (17 episodes) = **$170 million**.
Season 8, $15 million per episode (6 episodes) = **$90 million**.

So, in total, approximate: **$560 million**.

Comment: So, providing we trust your math (which I do - well done have a point xx) thats pretty good value compared at least to 'Endgame' which cost $356 for 181 mins compared to the $560 for the 4,336 (approx.) mins of GOT.

Comment: $560M which doesn't include casting remunerations!!!

Comment: @ashveli it doesn't?

Comment: @ashveli .... do you have a reference for that comment?  Why would the budget not include cast remuneration?

Comment: I asked a question whether it does or doesn't, notice the '?' mark.

Comment: @ashveli No, I do not notice any question mark in any comment you have made.